# How to draw tensorflow js results to canvas? Problems with tf.browser.toPixels - shows old results only

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow.js

I am new to JS. I have a ML model which does image segmentation. I provide the model with one image, to which it predicts output. I get the correct output array, I've verified.

But when I try to draw this output to a canvas using `tf.browser.toPixel` I always get the old Image.

Meaning, If I provide input as:

```
Input : img1 -> img2 -> img3...

output: <random shape> -> img1_prediction -> img2_prediction...
```

Where the `random shape` is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtlr0.png) always, no matter what the input is.
I've checked, this is not the output of my model.

Here's the code for this:

```
async function detect_custom(imgTag, canvas) {

    let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(imgTag).toFloat(); //imgTag is img element in html (input image)
    tensor = tensor.expandDims(0);
    const res = model.predict(tensor).squeeze(); 
    tf.dispose(tensor);
    // Everything is working correctly up to this point.

    await tf.browser.toPixels(res, canvas); // Problematic (I think)
}
```

I found the `await tf.browser.toPixels(res, canvas)` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64485288) answer. Can anyone help what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I've checked, this is not the output of my model.

What is the output of the model?

And are you sure it takes 0..255 as input range? if input is `float32`, its likely expecting values in range 0..1 - and it does seems like output is blown up.

try `tensor = tensor.div(255.0)` before inference to normalize to 0..1
or `tensor = tensor.div(127.5).sub(1)` to normalize to -1..1